# alignment of customized shape in 3d space

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have learned tikz for a short time. Recently I am writing a package with tikz to draw cubes in deep neural networks.

I have set the base shape and anchor (for labeling) I need. Then I consider the alignment of two adjacent block such as center alignment in x axis. First I draw a block at origin, then I draw a smaller block right of the previous block by using `positioning` package. It just shift right in x axis, and is not totally centered. In other words, it certered in y axis only and need shift in z axis to be center aligned in 3d space.

I write a demo and achive the performance. I implement the function of alignment in `block/.code`, which I think is not a good way. Is there some better method to do the same thing?

`dnnplot.syt`

```
\ProvidesPackage{dnnplot}
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\makeatletter
\let\pdfstrcmp=\pdf@strcmp
\pgfkeys{/block plot/.cd,
  width/.store in=\block@width, width=1cm,
  height/.store in=\block@height, height=1cm,
  channel/.store in=\block@channel, channel=1cm,
  scale/.store in=\block@scale, scale=.1,
  pre/.store in=\block@pre, pre=,
  align/.store in=\block@align, align=,
}
\pgfdeclareshape{base block}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \saveddimen{\offset}{\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\block@offset}}
  \anchor{back north west}{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \northeast
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@xa + \offset}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgf@y + \offset}
  }
  \anchor{back north east}{
    \northeast
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@x + \offset}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgf@y + \offset}
  }
  \anchor{back south east}{
    \northeast \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \southwest
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgf@xa + \offset}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgf@y + \offset}
  }
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \def\block@offset{\pgfqpoint{\offset}{\offset}}
    % main path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\block@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\block@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\block@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    % other edge
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\block@offset}}
  }
}
\tikzset{
  block/.code={\tikzset{/block plot/.cd, #1}
    % scale
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@width{\block@scale*\block@width}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@height{\block@scale*\block@height}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@channel{\block@scale*\block@channel}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\block@offset{sqrt(2)/4*\scaled@width}
    % shift
    \ifx\block@pre\pgfutil@empty
    \else\ifx\block@align\pgfutil@empty
    \else
      \tikzmath{
        coordinate \pre@offset, \cur@offset, \block@shift;
        \pre@offset = (\block@pre.back north west) - (\block@pre.north west);
        \cur@offset = (\block@offset, \block@offset);
        \block@shift = (0, 0);
        if \pdf@strcmp{\block@align}{center}==0 then{
          \block@shift = ($0.5*(\pre@offset) - 0.5*(\cur@offset)$);
        } else{};
      }
      \tikzset{shift={(\block@shift)}}
    \fi\fi
    % general
    \tikzset{
      base block, draw, opacity=.2,
      minimum height=\scaled@height,
      minimum width=\scaled@channel,
    }
  }
}
\newcommand{\blocklabel}[3]{
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#2}{back east}=0
    \path (#1.back south east) -- node[right] {#3} (#1.back north east);
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

`tikz.tex`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math, positioning}
\usepackage{dnnplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill=red, block={scale=1.5, width=50mm, height=50mm, channel=20mm}](a){};
  \fill[blue] (a.center) circle (1pt);
  \fill[fill=red] (a.north east) node[anchor=west] {north east} circle (1pt);
  \fill[fill=red] (a.north west) circle (1pt);
  \fill[fill=red] (a.south east) circle (1pt);
  \fill[fill=red] (a.south west) circle (1pt);
  \fill[fill=red] (a.back north east) circle (1pt);
  \fill[fill=red] (a.back north west) circle (1pt);
  \fill[fill=red] (a.back south east) circle (1pt);
  \blocklabel{a}{back east}{back east label}
  \node[fill=green, right=4cm of a, block={scale=1.5, width=10mm, height=10mm,
    channel=10mm}](b){};
  \node[fill=green, right=4cm of a, block={scale=1.5, width=10mm, height=10mm,
    channel=10mm, pre=a, align=center}](c){};
  \draw (a.center) --node[above]{shift in x-axis} (b.center);
  \draw[draw=red, ->] (b.center) -- node[right]{shift in z-axis}(c.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! It is already amazing that you managed to store and retrieve the depth `pre` in the way you did. Unfortunately, Ti*k*Z has major conceptional problems with 3d coordinates since internally it only uses 2d coordinates, And of course in retrospect it is impossible to undo the projections. There are [some developments](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/31165f2f43d419e1a921a1881bf25743592577a7/) in a direction that may ultimately help, but progress is slow.  (And `dnnplot.sty`, please ;-)

Comment: ... and other attempts can be found [here](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools). Everything is far from perfect. On would have to store the 3d coordinates in a 3d reference frame such that one always can compare points.

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is that you might not take the standard anchors in the front plane, but in the center of the shape. That is, there will be four additional anchors on the front plane. Then the center will be the 3d center, and you can use standard positioning.

Comment: Multi-style of aligment is needed such as aligning along one side instead of centering, so I think shifting is indispensable.

Comment: Really? Right now you can say `   \node[fill=green, right=2mm of a.south east,
    anchor=south west,
    block={scale=1.5, width=10mm, height=10mm,
     channel=10mm}](b){};` and `\node[fill=green, right=2mm of a.back south east,
    anchor=south west,
    block={scale=1.5, width=10mm, height=10mm,
     channel=10mm}](b){};`. If you add anchors for the front, you will have more options. Of course, in order to be able to position using the anchors of the second node, one needs to work more. BTW, `\blocklabel{a}{back east}{back east label}` does not work on my machine.

Comment: Making center the real 3d center is a good idea! I will try it.

Comment: But when I want top alignment, shifting in y axis is still needed. What's more, if blocks are placed along z axis, alignment and shifting will be a more complex thing.

Comment: If there had been `front of` and `back of` in positioning ~_~