# A strange bug when I write my package with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is the mwe. It seems that when align the block in the left and right, it shifts a bit more in z axis so that it is not aligned. But shifting in y axis is normal. In my package code, the two ways of alignment are implement similarly. I have tried to comment some code that may cause problem, which made no effort.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\usepackage{dnnplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    test/.style={
      fill=green, right=4cm of a,
      block={scale=1, width=20mm, height=20mm, channel=10mm, pre=a, align=#1}
    }
  }
  \node[fill=red, block={scale=1.5, width=50mm, height=50mm, channel=10mm,
    back plot}](a){};
{center};
  \node[test=center] (b) {};
  \draw[red, line width=1pt, ->] (a.east) -- (b.east);
  \foreach \t in {left, right, up, down, upperright, upperleft, lowerleft,
    lowerright}{
    \node[test=\t] (\t) {};
  }
  \draw[dashed] (a.north east) -- (up.north west);
  \draw[dashed] (a.south east) -- (down.south west);
  \draw[dashed] ($(a.front north east)!.5!(a.front south east)$) -- ($(left.front
    north west)!.5!(left.front south west)$);
  \draw[dashed] ($(a.back north east)!.5!(a.back south east)$) -- ($(right.back
    north west)!.5!(right.back south west)$);
  \draw[red] (a.north east) -- +(1cm, 0);
  \draw[red] (a.south east) -- +(1cm, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Below is the package code.

```
\ProvidesPackage{dnnplot}
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}

\makeatletter
\let\pdfstrcmp=\pdf@strcmp
\pgfkeys{/block plot/.cd,
  width/.store in=\block@width, width=1cm,
  height/.store in=\block@height, height=1cm,
  channel/.store in=\block@channel, channel=1cm,
  scale/.store in=\block@scale, scale=.5,
  pre/.store in=\block@pre, pre=,
  back plot/.store in=\block@back@plot, back plot=,
  back plot/.default=true,
  zshift/.store in=\block@zshift, zshift=0,
  front/.store in=\block@front, front=,
  align axis/.store in=\block@align@axis, align axis=x,
  hfactor/.store in=\block@hfactor, hfactor=.5,
  vfactor/.store in=\block@vfactor, vfactor=.5,
  align/.store in=\block@align, align=center,
}

\pgfdeclareshape{base block}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \saveddimen{\offset}{
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{
      sqrt(2)/8*\block@scale*\block@width
    }
  }
  \anchor{front}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \pgf@xa=.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@ya=.5\pgf@y
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
    \advance \pgf@x by \pgf@xa
    \advance \pgf@y by \pgf@ya
    \advance \pgf@x by -\offset
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset
  }
  \anchor{front south west}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \advance \pgf@x by -\offset
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset
  }
  \anchor{back south west}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \advance \pgf@x by \offset
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset
  }
  \anchor{front north east}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \advance \pgf@x by -\offset
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset
  }
  \anchor{back north east}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \advance \pgf@x by \offset
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset
  }
  \anchor{front south east}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \advance \pgf@xa by -\offset
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa
  }
  \anchor{back south east}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \advance \pgf@xa by \offset
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa
  }
  \anchor{front north west}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \advance \pgf@xa by -\offset
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa
  }
  \anchor{back north west}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \advance \pgf@xa by \offset
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa
  }
  \backgroundpath{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \def\block@add@offset##1{
      \pgfpointadd{##1}{\pgfqpoint{\offset}{\offset}}
    }
    \def\block@sub@offset##1{
      \pgfpointadd{##1}{\pgfqpoint{-\offset}{-\offset}}
    }
    \def\block@southwest{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \def\block@southeast{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \def\block@northeast{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \def\block@northwest{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    % main path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southwest}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@southeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northwest}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northwest}}
    \pgfpathclose
    % other edge
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northwest}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southeast}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northeast}}
  }
  \foregroundpath{
    % back plot
    \ifx\block@back@plot\pgfutil@empty
    \else
      \pgfsetdash{{1mm}{1mm}}{0mm}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\block@add@offset{\block@southwest}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southwest}}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\block@add@offset{\block@southwest}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northwest}}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\block@add@offset{\block@southwest}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@southeast}}
      \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \fi
  }
}

\tikzset{
  block/.code={\tikzset{/block plot/.cd, #1}
    % scale
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@width{\block@scale*\block@width}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@height{\block@scale*\block@height}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@channel{\block@scale*\block@channel}
    % shift
    % initial shift
    \def\block@shift{(0, 0)}
    % add to shift
    \def\shift@to@coordinate@x##1{(##1, 0)}
    \def\shift@to@coordinate@y##1{(0, ##1)}
    \def\shift@to@coordinate@z##1{{-sqrt(2)/4}*(##1, ##1)}
    % ##1 coordinate
    \def\update@block@shift##1{
      \edef\block@shift{($\block@shift+##1$)}
    }
    % ##1 x, y, z
    % ##2 shift length
    \def\add@to@shift##1##2{
      \update@block@shift{\csname shift@to@coordinate@##1\endcsname{##2}}
    }
    % shift in z axis
    \add@to@shift{z}{\block@zshift}
    % predefined macros
    % ##1 ##2 anchors ##3 factor
    \edef\pre@temp##1##2##3{##3*(\block@pre.##1)-##3*(\block@pre.##2)}
    % ##1 factor
    \def\pre@offset@x##1{\pre@temp{back north east}{back north west}{##1}}
    \def\pre@offset@y##1{\pre@temp{back north west}{back south west}{##1}}
    \def\pre@offset@z##1{\pre@temp{back north west}{front north west}{##1}}
    \def\cur@offset@x{(\scaled@channel, 0)}
    \def\cur@offset@y{(0, \scaled@height)}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{sqrt(2)/4*\scaled@width}
    \def\cur@offset@z{(\pgfutil@tempdima, \pgfutil@tempdima)}
    % total shift (with factor 1)
    % ##1 x, y, z ##2 factor
    \edef\shift@x##1{\pre@offset@x{{##1}} - {##1}*\cur@offset@x}
    \edef\shift@y##1{\pre@offset@y{{##1}} - {##1}*\cur@offset@y}
    \edef\shift@z##1{\pre@offset@z{{##1}} - {##1}*\cur@offset@z}
    \ifx\block@pre\pgfutil@empty
    \else
      % front of shift
      \ifx\block@front\pgfutil@empty
      \else
        \update@block@shift{\pre@offset@z{{-0.5}}}
        \add@to@shift{z}{\scaled@width}
        \add@to@shift{z}{\block@front}
      \fi
      % align shift
      % align option has higher priority
      % ##1 shift style ##2 hfactor ##3 vfactor
      \def\shift@style##1##2##3{
        \expandafter\def\csname block@shift@##1\endcsname{
          \def\block@hfactor{##2}
          \def\block@vfactor{##3}
        }
      }
      \shift@style{left}{0}{0.5}
      \shift@style{right}{1}{0.5}
      \shift@style{down}{0.5}{0}
      \shift@style{up}{0.5}{1}
      \shift@style{upperleft}{0}{1}
      \shift@style{upperright}{1}{1}
      \shift@style{lowerleft}{0}{0}
      \shift@style{lowerright}{1}{0}
      \ifcsname block@shift@\block@align\endcsname
        \csname block@shift@\block@align\endcsname
      \fi
      % hshift and vshift in 3 directions
      \pgfmathsetmacro\real@hfactor{\block@hfactor-0.5}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\real@vfactor{\block@vfactor-0.5}
      \def\define@hv@shift##1##2##3{
        \expandafter\edef\csname hshift@##1\endcsname{
          \csname shift@##2\endcsname{\real@hfactor}
        }
        \expandafter\edef\csname vshift@##1\endcsname{
          \csname shift@##3\endcsname{\real@vfactor}
        }
      }
      \define@hv@shift{x}{z}{y}
      \define@hv@shift{y}{x}{z}
      \define@hv@shift{z}{x}{y}
      \ifcsname hshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname
        \csname hshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname
        \update@block@shift{
          \csname hshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname +
          \csname vshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname
        }
      \fi
    \fi
    % general
    \tikzset{
      shift={\block@shift},
      base block, draw, fill opacity=.2, thick,
      minimum height=\scaled@height,
      minimum width=\scaled@channel,
    }
  }
}

\def\block@label@upperleft@a{front north west}
\def\block@label@upperleft@b{back north west}
\def\block@label@upperright@a{front north east}
\def\block@label@upperright@b{back north east}
\def\block@label@lowerleft@a{front south west}
\def\block@label@lowerleft@b{back south west}
\def\block@label@lowerright@a{front south east}
\def\block@label@lowerright@b{back south east}
\def\block@label@frontwest@a{front south west}
\def\block@label@frontwest@b{front north west}
\def\block@label@fronteast@a{front south east}
\def\block@label@fronteast@b{front north east}
\def\block@label@backwest@a{back south west}
\def\block@label@backwest@b{back north west}
\def\block@label@backeast@a{back south east}
\def\block@label@backeast@b{back north east}
\def\block@label@frontsouth@a{front south west}
\def\block@label@frontsouth@b{front south east}
\def\block@label@frontnorth@a{front north west}
\def\block@label@frontnorth@b{front north east}
\def\block@label@backsouth@a{back south west}
\def\block@label@backsouth@b{back south east}
\def\block@label@backnorth@a{back north west}
\def\block@label@backnorth@b{back north east}
% #1 -- label position
% #2 -- node name
% #3 -- passed string
% #4 -- label text
% #5 -- edge specification
\newcommand{\block@label}[4]{
  \path (#2.\csname block@label@#3@a\endcsname) --
        node[#1] {#4}
        (#2.\csname block@label@#3@b\endcsname);
}
\def\block@label@position@upperleft{left}
\def\block@label@position@upperright{right}
\def\block@label@position@lowerleft{left}
\def\block@label@position@lowerright{right}
\def\block@label@position@frontwest{left}
\def\block@label@position@fronteast{right}
\def\block@label@position@backwest{left}
\def\block@label@position@backeast{right}
\def\block@label@position@frontnorth{above}
\def\block@label@position@frontsouth{below}
\def\block@label@position@backnorth{above}
\def\block@label@position@backsouth{above}
% #1 -- label position, optional
% #2 -- node name
% #3 -- passed string
% #4 -- label text
\newcommand{\blocklabel}[4][]{
  \ifcsname block@label@position@#3\endcsname
    \def\block@label@position{#1}
    % use default position
    \ifx\block@label@position\pgfutil@empty
      \def\block@label@position{\csname block@label@position@#3\endcsname}
    \fi
    \block@label{\block@label@position}{#2}{#3}{#4}
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I forget one line of code. Now it is complete.

Comment: I added `\typeout`s to monitor the `\block@shift`. And I get `($($(0, 0)+({-0*sqrt(2)/2}, {-0*sqrt(2)/2})$)+  {-0.5}*(a.back north west)-{-0.
5}*(a.front north west) - {-0.5}*(\pgfutil@tempdima , \pgfutil@tempdima ) +  {0
.0}*(a.back north west)-{0.0}*(a.back south west) - {0.0}*(0, 56.9055pt) $)` for example. So it might be an expansion issue: `\pgfutil@tempdima` is not expanded, and may assume other values when you use the  `\block@shift` because it got overwritten. Overall I would recommend not using the `calc` syntax to accumulate the shift.

Comment: Thanks for help, I will consider it tommorow. It has been midnight in China, good night.

Comment: Are you *really* sure about `\let\pdfstrcmp\pdf@strcmp`? Any usage of `\pdfstrcmp` or `\pdf@strcmp` would lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: This line was added when I test my code and I'm using xelatex. Now it is unused.

Comment: I have a question that if I don't use `calc` how can I extract the x, y coordinate from a anchor of passed node.

Comment: I have known how to extract coordinates without calc. I'm using this way to accumulate the shift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned under your previous question, I am really impressed by what you have achieved. IMHO this is one of the most astonishing developments in Ti*k*Z in a while.

As for your question: by replacing your style file by

```
\ProvidesPackage{dnnplot}
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}

\makeatletter
%\let\pdfstrcmp=\pdf@strcmp%
% removed, see see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516078/alignment-of-customized-shape-in-3d-space#comment1304939_516078
\pgfkeys{/block plot/.cd,
  width/.store in=\block@width, width=1cm,
  height/.store in=\block@height, height=1cm,
  channel/.store in=\block@channel, channel=1cm,
  scale/.store in=\block@scale, scale=.5,
  pre/.store in=\block@pre, pre=,
  back plot/.store in=\block@back@plot, back plot=,
  back plot/.default=true,
  zshift/.store in=\block@zshift, zshift=0,
  front/.store in=\block@front, front=,
  align axis/.store in=\block@align@axis, align axis=x,
  hfactor/.store in=\block@hfactor, hfactor=.5,
  vfactor/.store in=\block@vfactor, vfactor=.5,
  align/.store in=\block@align, align=center,
}

\pgfdeclareshape{base block}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \saveddimen{\offset}{
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{
      sqrt(2)/8*\block@scale*\block@width
    }
  }
  \anchor{front}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \pgf@xa=.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@ya=.5\pgf@y
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
    \advance \pgf@x by \pgf@xa
    \advance \pgf@y by \pgf@ya
    \advance \pgf@x by -\offset
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset
  }
  \anchor{front south west}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \advance \pgf@x by -\offset
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset
  }
  \anchor{back south west}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \advance \pgf@x by \offset
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset
  }
  \anchor{front north east}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \advance \pgf@x by -\offset
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset
  }
  \anchor{back north east}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \advance \pgf@x by \offset
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset
  }
  \anchor{front south east}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \advance \pgf@xa by -\offset
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa
  }
  \anchor{back south east}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \advance \pgf@xa by \offset
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa
  }
  \anchor{front north west}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \advance \pgf@xa by -\offset
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa
  }
  \anchor{back north west}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \advance \pgf@xa by \offset
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa
  }
  \backgroundpath{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \def\block@add@offset##1{
      \pgfpointadd{##1}{\pgfqpoint{\offset}{\offset}}
    }
    \def\block@sub@offset##1{
      \pgfpointadd{##1}{\pgfqpoint{-\offset}{-\offset}}
    }
    \def\block@southwest{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \def\block@southeast{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \def\block@northeast{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \def\block@northwest{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    % main path
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southwest}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@southeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northwest}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northwest}}
    \pgfpathclose
    % other edge
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northwest}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southeast}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northeast}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northeast}}
  }
  \foregroundpath{
    % back plot
    \ifx\block@back@plot\pgfutil@empty
    \else
      \pgfsetdash{{1mm}{1mm}}{0mm}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\block@add@offset{\block@southwest}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southwest}}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\block@add@offset{\block@southwest}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northwest}}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\block@add@offset{\block@southwest}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@southeast}}
      \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \fi
  }
}

\tikzset{
  block/.code={\tikzset{/block plot/.cd, #1}
    % scale
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@width{\block@scale*\block@width}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@height{\block@scale*\block@height}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@channel{\block@scale*\block@channel}
    % shift
    % initial shift
    \def\block@shift{(0, 0)}
    % add to shift
    %\def\tikz@shift@to@coordinate@x{}
    \def\shift@to@coordinate@x##1{(##1, 0)}%
    \def\shift@to@coordinate@y##1{(0, ##1)}%
    \def\shift@to@coordinate@z##1{({-##1*sqrt(2)/2}, {-##1*sqrt(2)/2})}%
    % ##1 coordinate
    \def\update@block@shift##1{
      \edef\block@shift{($\block@shift+##1$)}
    }
    % ##1 x, y, z
    % ##2 shift length
    \def\add@to@shift##1##2{
      \update@block@shift{\csname shift@to@coordinate@##1\endcsname{##2}}
    }
    % shift in z axis
    \add@to@shift{z}{\block@zshift}
    % predefined macros
    % ##1 ##2 anchors ##3 factor
    \edef\pre@temp##1##2##3{##3*(\block@pre.##1)-##3*(\block@pre.##2)}
    % ##1 factor
    \def\pre@offset@x##1{\pre@temp{back north east}{back north west}{##1}}
    \def\pre@offset@y##1{\pre@temp{back north west}{back south west}{##1}}
    \def\pre@offset@z##1{\pre@temp{back north west}{front north west}{##1}}
    \def\cur@offset@x{(\scaled@channel, 0)}
    \def\cur@offset@y{(0, \scaled@height)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfutil@tempa{sqrt(2)/4*\scaled@width}
    \edef\cur@offset@z{(\pgfutil@tempa pt, \pgfutil@tempa pt)}
    % total shift (with factor 1)
    % ##1 x, y, z ##2 factor
    \edef\shift@x##1{\pre@offset@x{{##1}} - {##1}*\cur@offset@x}
    \edef\shift@y##1{\pre@offset@y{{##1}} - {##1}*\cur@offset@y}
    \edef\shift@z##1{\pre@offset@z{{##1}} - {##1}*\cur@offset@z}
    \ifx\block@pre\pgfutil@empty
    \else
      % front of shift
      \ifx\block@front\pgfutil@empty
      \else
        \update@block@shift{\pre@offset@z{{-0.5}}}
        \add@to@shift{z}{\scaled@width}
        \add@to@shift{z}{\block@front}
      \fi
      % align shift
      % align option has higher priority
      % ##1 shift style ##2 hfactor ##3 vfactor
      \def\shift@style##1##2##3{
        \expandafter\def\csname block@shift@##1\endcsname{
          \def\block@hfactor{##2}
          \def\block@vfactor{##3}
        }
      }
      \shift@style{left}{0}{0.5}
      \shift@style{right}{1}{0.5}
      \shift@style{down}{0.5}{0}
      \shift@style{up}{0.5}{1}
      \shift@style{upperleft}{0}{1}
      \shift@style{upperright}{1}{1}
      \shift@style{lowerleft}{0}{0}
      \shift@style{lowerright}{1}{0}
      \ifcsname block@shift@\block@align\endcsname
        \csname block@shift@\block@align\endcsname
      \fi
      % hshift and vshift in 3 directions
      \pgfmathsetmacro\real@hfactor{\block@hfactor-0.5}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\real@vfactor{\block@vfactor-0.5}
      \def\define@hv@shift##1##2##3{
        \expandafter\edef\csname hshift@##1\endcsname{
          \csname shift@##2\endcsname{\real@hfactor}
        }
        \expandafter\edef\csname vshift@##1\endcsname{
          \csname shift@##3\endcsname{\real@vfactor}
        }
      }
      \define@hv@shift{x}{z}{y}
      \define@hv@shift{y}{x}{z}
      \define@hv@shift{z}{x}{y}
      \ifcsname hshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname
        \csname hshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname
        \update@block@shift{
          \csname hshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname +
          \csname vshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname
        }
      \fi
    \fi
    % general
    \tikzset{
      shift/.expanded={\block@shift},
      base block, draw, fill opacity=.2, thick,
      minimum height=\scaled@height,
      minimum width=\scaled@channel,
    }
  }
}

\def\block@label@upperleft@a{front north west}
\def\block@label@upperleft@b{back north west}
\def\block@label@upperright@a{front north east}
\def\block@label@upperright@b{back north east}
\def\block@label@lowerleft@a{front south west}
\def\block@label@lowerleft@b{back south west}
\def\block@label@lowerright@a{front south east}
\def\block@label@lowerright@b{back south east}
\def\block@label@frontwest@a{front south west}
\def\block@label@frontwest@b{front north west}
\def\block@label@fronteast@a{front south east}
\def\block@label@fronteast@b{front north east}
\def\block@label@backwest@a{back south west}
\def\block@label@backwest@b{back north west}
\def\block@label@backeast@a{back south east}
\def\block@label@backeast@b{back north east}
\def\block@label@frontsouth@a{front south west}
\def\block@label@frontsouth@b{front south east}
\def\block@label@frontnorth@a{front north west}
\def\block@label@frontnorth@b{front north east}
\def\block@label@backsouth@a{back south west}
\def\block@label@backsouth@b{back south east}
\def\block@label@backnorth@a{back north west}
\def\block@label@backnorth@b{back north east}
% #1 -- label position
% #2 -- node name
% #3 -- passed string
% #4 -- label text
% #5 -- edge specification
\newcommand{\block@label}[4]{
  \path (#2.\csname block@label@#3@a\endcsname) --
        node[#1] {#4}
        (#2.\csname block@label@#3@b\endcsname);
}
\def\block@label@position@upperleft{left}
\def\block@label@position@upperright{right}
\def\block@label@position@lowerleft{left}
\def\block@label@position@lowerright{right}
\def\block@label@position@frontwest{left}
\def\block@label@position@fronteast{right}
\def\block@label@position@backwest{left}
\def\block@label@position@backeast{right}
\def\block@label@position@frontnorth{above}
\def\block@label@position@frontsouth{below}
\def\block@label@position@backnorth{above}
\def\block@label@position@backsouth{above}
% #1 -- label position, optional
% #2 -- node name
% #3 -- passed string
% #4 -- label text
\newcommand{\blocklabel}[4][]{
  \ifcsname block@label@position@#3\endcsname
    \def\block@label@position{#1}
    % use default position
    \ifx\block@label@position\pgfutil@empty
      \def\block@label@position{\csname block@label@position@#3\endcsname}
    \fi
    \block@label{\block@label@position}{#2}{#3}{#4}
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

your MWE produces

[image]

The important change was to use

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfutil@tempa{sqrt(2)/4*\scaled@width}
\edef\cur@offset@z{(\pgfutil@tempa pt, \pgfutil@tempa pt)}
```

instead of

```
\pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{sqrt(2)/4*\scaled@width}
\def\cur@offset@z{(\pgfutil@tempdima, \pgfutil@tempdima)}
```

As mentioned in the comments, the `\pgfutil@tempa` did not get expanded. So it assumed a different value when it was used. Of course, this choice is not unique, e.g.

```
\pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{sqrt(2)/4*\scaled@width}
\edef\cur@offset@z{(\the\pgfutil@tempdima, \the\pgfutil@tempdima)}%
```

would also work. Here are a few more off-topic suggestions: end every line with a `%` to avoid spurious spaces. It should not matter in a `tikzpicture`, but it might be a good practice. Also, in a package you do not need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. So you could use

```
\ProvidesPackage{dnnplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfkeys{/block plot/.cd,
  width/.store in=\block@width, width=1cm,
  height/.store in=\block@height, height=1cm,
  channel/.store in=\block@channel, channel=1cm,
  scale/.store in=\block@scale, scale=.5,
  pre/.store in=\block@pre, pre=,
  back plot/.store in=\block@back@plot, back plot=,
  back plot/.default=true,
  zshift/.store in=\block@zshift, zshift=0,
  front/.store in=\block@front, front=,
  align axis/.store in=\block@align@axis, align axis=x,
  hfactor/.store in=\block@hfactor, hfactor=.5,
  vfactor/.store in=\block@vfactor, vfactor=.5,
  align/.store in=\block@align, align=center,
}

\pgfdeclareshape{base block}
{%
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]%
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}%
  \saveddimen{\offset}{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{%
      sqrt(2)/8*\block@scale*\block@width%
    }%
  }%
  \anchor{front}{%
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \pgf@xa=.5\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=.5\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y%
    \advance \pgf@x by \pgf@xa%
    \advance \pgf@y by \pgf@ya%
    \advance \pgf@x by -\offset%
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset%
  }%
  \anchor{front south west}{%
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \advance \pgf@x by -\offset%
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset%
  }%
  \anchor{back south west}{%
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \advance \pgf@x by \offset%
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset%
  }%
  \anchor{front north east}{%
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \advance \pgf@x by -\offset%
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset%
  }%
  \anchor{back north east}{%
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \advance \pgf@x by \offset%
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset%
  }%
  \anchor{front south east}{%
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \advance \pgf@xa by -\offset%
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset%
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa%
  }%
  \anchor{back south east}{%
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \advance \pgf@xa by \offset%
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset%
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa%
  }%
  \anchor{front north west}{%
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \advance \pgf@xa by -\offset%
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \advance \pgf@y by -\offset%
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa%
  }%
  \anchor{back north west}{%
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \advance \pgf@xa by \offset%
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \advance \pgf@y by \offset%
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa%
  }%
  \backgroundpath{%
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    \def\block@add@offset##1{%
      \pgfpointadd{##1}{\pgfqpoint{\offset}{\offset}}%
    }%
    \def\block@sub@offset##1{%
      \pgfpointadd{##1}{\pgfqpoint{-\offset}{-\offset}}%
    }%
    \def\block@southwest{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \def\block@southeast{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \def\block@northeast{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \def\block@northwest{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}%
    % main path%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southwest}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southeast}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@southeast}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northeast}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northwest}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northwest}}%
    \pgfpathclose%
    % other edge%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northeast}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northwest}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northeast}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southeast}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\block@sub@offset{\block@northeast}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northeast}}%
  }%
  \foregroundpath{%
    % back plot%
    \ifx\block@back@plot\pgfutil@empty%
    \else%
      \pgfsetdash{{1mm}{1mm}}{0mm}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\block@add@offset{\block@southwest}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\block@sub@offset{\block@southwest}}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\block@add@offset{\block@southwest}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@northwest}}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\block@add@offset{\block@southwest}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\block@add@offset{\block@southeast}}%
      \pgfusepath{stroke}%
    \fi%
  }%
}%
%
\tikzset{%
  block/.code={\tikzset{/block plot/.cd, #1}%
    % scale%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@width{\block@scale*\block@width}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@height{\block@scale*\block@height}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\scaled@channel{\block@scale*\block@channel}%
    % shift%
    % initial shift%
    \def\block@shift{(0, 0)}%
    % add to shift%
    %\def\tikz@shift@to@coordinate@x{}%
    \def\shift@to@coordinate@x##1{(##1, 0)}%%
    \def\shift@to@coordinate@y##1{(0, ##1)}%%
    \def\shift@to@coordinate@z##1{({-##1*sqrt(2)/2}, {-##1*sqrt(2)/2})}%%
    % ##1 coordinate%
    \def\update@block@shift##1{%
      \edef\block@shift{($\block@shift+##1$)}%
    }%
    % ##1 x, y, z%
    % ##2 shift length%
    \def\add@to@shift##1##2{%
      \update@block@shift{\csname shift@to@coordinate@##1\endcsname{##2}}%
    }%
    % shift in z axis%
    \add@to@shift{z}{\block@zshift}%
    % predefined macros%
    % ##1 ##2 anchors ##3 factor%
    \edef\pre@temp##1##2##3{##3*(\block@pre.##1)-##3*(\block@pre.##2)}%
    % ##1 factor%
    \def\pre@offset@x##1{\pre@temp{back north east}{back north west}{##1}}%
    \def\pre@offset@y##1{\pre@temp{back north west}{back south west}{##1}}%
    \def\pre@offset@z##1{\pre@temp{back north west}{front north west}{##1}}%
    \def\cur@offset@x{(\scaled@channel, 0)}%
    \def\cur@offset@y{(0, \scaled@height)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfutil@tempa{sqrt(2)/4*\scaled@width}%
     \edef\cur@offset@z{(\pgfutil@tempa pt, \pgfutil@tempa pt)}%
    % total shift (with factor 1)%
    % ##1 x, y, z ##2 factor%
    \edef\shift@x##1{\pre@offset@x{{##1}} - {##1}*\cur@offset@x}%
    \edef\shift@y##1{\pre@offset@y{{##1}} - {##1}*\cur@offset@y}%
    \edef\shift@z##1{\pre@offset@z{{##1}} - {##1}*\cur@offset@z}%
    \ifx\block@pre\pgfutil@empty%
    \else%
      % front of shift%
      \ifx\block@front\pgfutil@empty%
      \else%
        \update@block@shift{\pre@offset@z{{-0.5}}}%
        \add@to@shift{z}{\scaled@width}%
        \add@to@shift{z}{\block@front}%
      \fi%
      % align shift%
      % align option has higher priority%
      % ##1 shift style ##2 hfactor ##3 vfactor%
      \def\shift@style##1##2##3{%
        \expandafter\def\csname block@shift@##1\endcsname{%
          \def\block@hfactor{##2}%
          \def\block@vfactor{##3}%
        }%
      }%
      \shift@style{left}{0}{0.5}%
      \shift@style{right}{1}{0.5}%
      \shift@style{down}{0.5}{0}%
      \shift@style{up}{0.5}{1}%
      \shift@style{upperleft}{0}{1}%
      \shift@style{upperright}{1}{1}%
      \shift@style{lowerleft}{0}{0}%
      \shift@style{lowerright}{1}{0}%
      \ifcsname block@shift@\block@align\endcsname%
        \csname block@shift@\block@align\endcsname%
      \fi%
      % hshift and vshift in 3 directions%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\real@hfactor{\block@hfactor-0.5}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\real@vfactor{\block@vfactor-0.5}%
      \def\define@hv@shift##1##2##3{%
        \expandafter\edef\csname hshift@##1\endcsname{%
          \csname shift@##2\endcsname{\real@hfactor}%
        }%
        \expandafter\edef\csname vshift@##1\endcsname{%
          \csname shift@##3\endcsname{\real@vfactor}%
        }%
      }%
      \define@hv@shift{x}{z}{y}%
      \define@hv@shift{y}{x}{z}%
      \define@hv@shift{z}{x}{y}%
      \ifcsname hshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname%
        \csname hshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname%
        \update@block@shift{%
          \csname hshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname +%
          \csname vshift@\block@align@axis\endcsname%
        }%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    % general%
    \tikzset{%
      shift/.expanded={\block@shift},%
      base block, draw, fill opacity=.2, thick,%
      minimum height=\scaled@height,%
      minimum width=\scaled@channel,%
    }%
  }%
}%
%
\def\block@label@upperleft@a{front north west}%
\def\block@label@upperleft@b{back north west}%
\def\block@label@upperright@a{front north east}%
\def\block@label@upperright@b{back north east}%
\def\block@label@lowerleft@a{front south west}%
\def\block@label@lowerleft@b{back south west}%
\def\block@label@lowerright@a{front south east}%
\def\block@label@lowerright@b{back south east}%
\def\block@label@frontwest@a{front south west}%
\def\block@label@frontwest@b{front north west}%
\def\block@label@fronteast@a{front south east}%
\def\block@label@fronteast@b{front north east}%
\def\block@label@backwest@a{back south west}%
\def\block@label@backwest@b{back north west}%
\def\block@label@backeast@a{back south east}%
\def\block@label@backeast@b{back north east}%
\def\block@label@frontsouth@a{front south west}%
\def\block@label@frontsouth@b{front south east}%
\def\block@label@frontnorth@a{front north west}%
\def\block@label@frontnorth@b{front north east}%
\def\block@label@backsouth@a{back south west}%
\def\block@label@backsouth@b{back south east}%
\def\block@label@backnorth@a{back north west}%
\def\block@label@backnorth@b{back north east}%
% #1 -- label position%
% #2 -- node name%
% #3 -- passed string%
% #4 -- label text%
% #5 -- edge specification%
\newcommand{\block@label}[4]{%
  \path (#2.\csname block@label@#3@a\endcsname) --%
        node[#1] {#4}%
        (#2.\csname block@label@#3@b\endcsname);%
}%
\def\block@label@position@upperleft{left}%
\def\block@label@position@upperright{right}%
\def\block@label@position@lowerleft{left}%
\def\block@label@position@lowerright{right}%
\def\block@label@position@frontwest{left}%
\def\block@label@position@fronteast{right}%
\def\block@label@position@backwest{left}%
\def\block@label@position@backeast{right}%
\def\block@label@position@frontnorth{above}%
\def\block@label@position@frontsouth{below}%
\def\block@label@position@backnorth{above}%
\def\block@label@position@backsouth{above}%
% #1 -- label position, optional%
% #2 -- node name%
% #3 -- passed string%
% #4 -- label text%
\newcommand{\blocklabel}[4][]{%
  \ifcsname block@label@position@#3\endcsname%
    \def\block@label@position{#1}%
    % use default position%
    \ifx\block@label@position\pgfutil@empty%
      \def\block@label@position{\csname block@label@position@#3\endcsname}%
    \fi%
    \block@label{\block@label@position}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \fi%
}%
```

The biggest changes would be rewrite it in such a way that it works in arbitrary projections of 3d space (doable with moderate effort) and to do 3d ordering of the planes. The latter is doable but requires major efforts, or virtually impossible if Henri Menke really decides to revoke [this change](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/31165f2f43d419e1a921a1881bf25743592577a7/). I will only consider spelling this out if there is a guarantee that these (really good!) changes do not get revoked.

Comment: Let me mention that one could streamline some things but I am in a rush now.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have learned a lot from your answer and related links and realized there is a long way before I understand how macros actually work, which is  sad but encouraging for me.

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck You're welcome! As I already mentioned under the other question, what you have achieved is highly impressive, and will be useful for many. So I am glad that I could contribute a tiny bit. BTW, if the answer solves your problem, could you perhaps consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark on its left. (I plan to also add some more proposals for minor changes.)

Comment: Ok, glad to accept it (it is fun that I did not find the check mark before)!

Comment: Very amazing teamwork!!!!